# Split multidimensional array into columns by number of children

Tags: php, split, grouping

I have an array of objects grouped by letter name i.e:

```
['A' => array(obj, obj, obj), 'B' => array(obj), 'C' => array(obj, obj),
 'D' => array(obj, obj, obj, obj, obj), 'E' => array(obj, obj, obj, obj),...]
```

I'm trying to find a way to split this array into `X` columns (2 or 3) based on the number of objects in each array. The counts for my example are `[3, 1, 2, 5, 4]`. Splitting into three columns should give me:

```
array([A,B,C], [D], [E])
```

I'm not sure if I'm approaching this problem the right way, or if there's a better way of doing this.

Edit:
I'm trying to code a page where the lists are grouped with headings a la Wikipedia categories e.g.: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Arts.

Comment: Can you be more concrete about your algorithm for chunking the array?

Comment: I don't have anything yet. I'm not quite sure where to start.

Comment: In response to your edit: Why do you need them chunked like this in the first place? Are you just trying to make it look nicer on the front end? If so, just style it differently in your css or js.

Comment: I can, but all the examples I've seen so far recommend adding class names which isn't something I can do with a variable length list.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `$input` is your array of arrays of objects, and `$numColumns` is however many columns you want...

```
uasort( $input, function( $x, $y ){ return count( $y ) - count( $x ); } );
$columns = array_chunk( $input, (int)ceil( count( $input ) / $numColumns ), true );
```

This sorts the input array based on the length of the sub-arrays, then splits it into `$numColumns` chunks. After this, `$columns` will be something like:

```
0 => array(
    'B' => array( obj ),
    'C' => array( obj, obj ),
    'A' => array( obj, obj, obj )     ),
1 => array(
    'D' => array( obj, obj, obj, obj ),
    'E' => array( obj, obj, obj, obj, obj )    ),
2 => array(
    'F' => array( lots of objs ),
    'G' => array( lots and lots of objs )    )
```

and so on.

Comment: Nice. The problem is I needed the items in the same order.

Comment: That's tougher. Off the top of my head: you could start by making an array of the counts. `$counts = array_map( function( $x ){ return count( $x ); }, $input );` Then `asort( $counts )` and use `array_chunk()` to split up the `$counts` array. Then you'd have to loop back through `$input` and use `array_search()` to see which subarray of `$counts` each key was in. Tedious but not impossible.